# Published my first Flutter package- gif are not showing up in my read me file

Tags: flutter, dart, pub.dev

Its showing on my github but not showing on pub.dev why?

github link
https://github.com/erayhamurlu/onboarding_plus

pub.dev link
https://pub.dev/packages/onboarding_plus

i hope someone show me i think it is a generic problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the image path, change this:

```
https://github.com/erayhamurlu/onboarding_plus/blob/main/screenshot1.png
```

to

```
https://github.com/erayhamurlu/onboarding_plus/raw/main/screenshot1.png
```

you need to replace `blob` to `raw` in your path. Do this for all three pictures.

Comment: I changed but for testing i need to send package to pub.dev ?

Comment: I think yes you need.

Comment: yeah update was necessary and worked thanks man.